# how to run a loop and update a plot at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

i am trying to write a code where i am running a function that controls the output of a particular device for a set period of time. also i have a second function that plots data from a sensor in real time. i am using multithreading module to run both the functions. however the plot becomes unresponsive. is there a better way of doing the same. will be very helpful if someone can comment on this.
i have presented a dummy code

`

```
import random
from itertools import count
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import time
import numpy as np

from IPython.display import display, clear_output

def funa(i):
    start=time.time()
    while time.time()-start<30:
        i=i+1
        print(i)


def show_fig():
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) 
    start=time.time()
    
    # Define and update plot
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    while time.time()-start<30:
        x = time.time()-start
        X.append(x)
        y = np.cos(x)
        Y.append(y)    
        ax.cla()
        ax.plot(X, Y)
        display(fig)    
        clear_output(wait = True)
        plt.pause(0.1)
            


import threading

        
thread1=threading.Thread(target=funa,args=(1,))
thread2=threading.Thread(target=show_fig)
a=time.time() 
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
print(time.time()-a)
```

`

Comment: Is it possible for you to give an example of how the output behaves ?

Comment: it will be difficult for me to show the output here because the matplotlib figure becomes unresponsive and the kernel restarts soon after.